Is there any way to split train/test database on multi feature? And how is unseen data?
I'm working on a Seq2Seq problem which is data to text problem.
Here are my concerns:

How do they define a sample is unseen? I mean it's seq2seq problem I don't think a sample just need a different character with ones in training set can be consider unseen.

In my data, I have some type of data (for e.g table name) and type of columns (column name). So I intend to split my data base on a set of names including table name and columns name.


Let's say:
 label_1, label_2, label_3, ... label_n
 1     0        1         1     0      1
 2     1        0         1     0      1
 3     0        0         1     0      1

I mean I don't expect my model can generalize on cases which have "strange" column name which my model hasn't met before (or should I expect that?) so the case 2 on example above shouldn't be included in test set. However, with the example 3. as label 3 and label_n are seen in sample 1. so it can be included in test set if sample 1 in train set.
